# How to print matching line, 3 lines after, and matching URL

Tags: awk, sed

I try to extract information from SMTP mails in text, i.e:

1. the date (ex: Wed, 9 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT)
2. the sender (ex: from xxx.yyy.com (zzz:com. [111.222.333.444])
3. URLs present in the mail (ex: http://some.thing)

Here's an example of an input:

```
Delivered-To: SOME@ADDRESS.COM
Received: by X.X.X.X with SMTP id SOMEID;
        Wed, 9 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by X.X.X.X with SMTP id SOMEID;
        Wed, 09 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <SOME@ADDRESS.COM>
Received: from SOME.URL.COM (SOME.OTHER.URL.COM. [X.X.X.X])
        by SOME.THIRD.URL.COM with ESMTP id SOMEID
        for <SOME@ADDRESS.COM>;
        Wed, 09 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT)
SOME_HTML
SOME_HTML
href="http://URL1"><img
SOME_HTML
src="http://URL2"
SOME_HTML
```

The example is deliberately truncated because the header is longer, but this is for the example

I've tried sed and awk and I managed to do some thing but not as I want.

**SED:**

```
sed -e 's/http/\nhttp/g' -n -e '/Received: from/{h;n;n;n;H;x;s/\n \+/;/;p}' a.txt
```

The first one is to have the URL on one lien but I didn't manage to use it after. 
And anyway, it's not in order.

**AWK:**

```
BEGIN{
    RS = "\n";
    FS = "";
}
/Received: from/{
    from = $0;
    getline;
    getline;
    getline;
    date = $0
}
/"\"https?://[^\"]+"/
{
    FS="\"";
    print $0;
}
END{
    print date";"from;
};
```

This one works except for the URL. The rexgexp doesn't works while in a oneline yes.
I also tried to find a more elegant way for the date by using the value of NR+3, but it didn't work.

And display this in csv format:

date;sender;URL1;URL2;...

I would prefer pure sed or pure awk, because I think I can do it with grep, tail, sed and awk but as I want to learn, I prefer one or both of them :)

Comment: What would be the output for the short input you provided? I don't know which urls to choose? Also It's better to parse html with html/xml aware tools, rather then with sed.

Comment: It would be ```Wed, 9 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT);Received: from SOME.URL.COM (SOME.OTHER.URL.COM. [X.X.X.X]);http://URL1;http://URL2```

Comment: We assume there is _only_(!) one `Received: from` and that the fourth line from it always has the date? (I ask, because smpt header is much more complicated). Well, you have `http://URL1><img` and from that you extracted `http://URL1` so `[^"]+` will not work. Or is there a `"` missing in the input?

Comment: For the URL, I don't know either, but as it's in a HTML, some typical regexp should work like this one with SED for example: ```sed -rne 's#.+?(https?://[^"]+).*#\1#p'```

Comment: Yes, I've based my code with that (one "Received; from") and if I remember well, I found one example where the date was on the second line, but I'm not sure... but for simplicity, consider that it's 3 lines below

Comment: You're right, there's a ```"``` missing in my example. I'm gonna edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the following longish sed script with comments inside:

```
sed -nE '
/Received: from /{
    # hold mu line!
    h

    # ach, spagetti code, here we go again
    : notdate
    ${
        s/.*/ERROR: INVALID INPUT: DATE NOT FOUND/
        p
        q1
    }
    # the next line after the line ending with ; should be the date
    /;$/!{
        # so search for a line ending with ;
        n
        b notdate
    }
    # the next line is the date
    n
    # remove leading spaces
    s/^[[:space:]]*//
    # grab the Received: from line
    G
    # and save it for later
    h
}

# headers end with an empty line
/^$/{
    # loop over lines
    : read_next_line
    n

    # flag with \x01<URL>\x02 all occurences of URLs
    s/"(http[^"]+)"/\x01\1\x02/g

    # we found at least one URL if there is \x01 in the pattern space
    /\x01/{

        # extract each occurence to the end of pattern  space with a newline
        : again
        s/^([^\x01]*)\x01([^\x02]*)\x02(.*)$/\1\3\n\2/
            t again

        # remove everything in front of separator - the unparsed part of line
        s/^[^\n]*\n//
        # add URLs to hold space
        H
    }

    # if this is the last line, we should finally print something!, and, exit
    ${
        # grab the hold space
        x
        # replace the separator for a ;
        s/\n/;/g
        # print and exit successfully
        p
        q 0
    }

    # here we go again!
    b read_next_line
}

'
```

for the following input:

```
Delivered-To: SOME@ADDRESS.COM
Received: by X.X.X.X with SMTP id SOMEID;
        Wed, 9 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by X.X.X.X with SMTP id SOMEID;
        Wed, 09 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <SOME@ADDRESS.COM>
Received: from SOME.URL.COM (SOME.OTHER.URL.COM. [X.X.X.X])
        by SOME.THIRD.URL.COM with ESMTP id SOMEID
        for <SOME@ADDRESS.COM>;
        Wed, 09 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT)

SOME_HTML
SOME_HTML
href="http://URL1"><img
SOME_HTML
src="http://URL2"
SOME_HTML
SOMEHTML src="http://URL3" SOMEHTML src="http://URL4"
```

outputs:

```
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 01:55:58 -0700 (PDT);Received: from SOME.URL.COM (SOME.OTHER.URL.COM. [X.X.X.X]);http://URL1;http://URL2;http://URL3;http://URL4
```

Comment: Two more questions for you: if I have several same URLS, is it possible to not duplicate these ones ? And I tried to put your batch in a script, but it returns an error: ```sed -f test.sed a.txt sed: file test.sed line 36: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS```. Do you have any idea ? Anyway, thank you for your script and your explnations !

Comment: `to not duplicate these ones` - this is extremely hard for sed job for sed and this script is already complicated and uses hold space. Rather then doing it in one sed, just read `sed`s output line by line in bash `sort -u` the urls and output them again. `invalid reference \1` I have written the `sed` using extended regexes, you have to use `-E` or `-r` or `--regexp-extended` flag with `sed`. You need GNU sed (or at least some good sed) for this script anyway, as I use `\n` and `\x01` and `\x02`, so it may not work on all `sed` implementation.

Comment: ```to not duplicate these ones```: allright, I'll try that. Otherwise, I think I can handle it with awk... ```invalid reference \1``` you're right, thid works :) Thanks again !